# Generic C# function to check duplicates (different objects, different fields)

Tags: c#, function, generics

I want to create a generic function the gets three arguments (a List of objects, a property name and a value) ... the function has to check for duplicates.
So :

```
class A  {
   public string description;
   public string abbreviation;
}

class B {
   public string description;
   public string name;
}
```

I have two List objects ... one with multiple class A objects and one with multiple class B objects.

```
List <A> listOfA
List <B> listOfB
```

I want a function called with something like this :

```
bool hasDuplicateAbbreviation = CheckDuplicate (listOfA, "abbreviation", "ALG");
bool hasDuplicateName = CheckDuplicate (listOfB, "name", "Mrs. Smith");
bool hasDuplicateDescription = CheckDuplicate (listOfB, "description", "Nice toolkit");
```

How should I do this ?

Nice to have would be if the same function could also be used for a class C with an integer rank :

```
class C  {
   public string description;
   public int rank;
}

List <C> listOfC

bool hasDuplicateRank = CheckDuplicate (listOfC, "rank", 2);
```

Comment: please add an example of an input and desired outputs

Comment: Why not simply use `Any`? `if(list.Any(v => v.Prop == value)) {/* duplicate found */}`

Comment: @ZoharPeled as the user says Generic function, so I assume they want to be able to use variable property (or field) name

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani `Any` is generic...

Comment: @ZoharPeled, that's not what I meant. I mean he is looking for a generic method, that can accept any type and name of any properties to check. in his examples, he tries it with different types and each time with a different property name : listOfA, "abbreviation" - listOfB, "name" - listOfB, "description".

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani `Any` takes in a `Predicate<T>` - the lambda expression can contain any type and any conditions inside, as long as it returns true.

Comment: ...I mean, as long as it returns true or false

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Reflection (need to import `System.Reflection`):

```
public static int CheckDuplicate<T>(IEnumerable<T> input, string field, object value)
{
    int count = 0;
    Type type = typeof(T);
    foreach(var item in input)
    {
        var fieldInfo = type.GetField(field);
        if(fieldInfo!= null)
            if(fieldInfo.GetValue(item) == value) count++;
        else
        {
            var propInfo = type.GetProperty(field);
            if(propInfo != null && propInfo.GetValue(item) == value) count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

This will return the number of times your given value is repeated.

```
if(CheckDuplicate(a, "abbreviation", "abbr1") > 1)
{
    // there is a duplicate
}
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/paPQCS)

Comment: I used a lot of your code ... thanks, got it working ! My post was strongly simplified, the input consists of 4 Lists, instead of 1, which need to be processed first before the unique check ... but got a lot of inspiration from this thread, so everybody's comment helped al lot ... thx again.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a function taking a generic list and a func pointing to the property you want to compare with and pass in the value you want to compare to like this:

```cs
public bool CheckDuplicate<T>(IEnumerable<T> items,
  Func<T, object> propertySelector,
  object value) =>
      items.Count(x => propertySelector(x).Equals(value)) > 1;
```

and consume it like this:

```cs
bool hasDuplicateAbbreviation = CheckDuplicate(listOfA, x => x.abbreviation, "ALG");
```

But the simplest (and recommended) solution is to use LINQ extension methods on the list directly instead like this:

```cs
bool hasDuplicateAbbreviation = listOfA.Count(x => x.abbreviation == "ALG") > 1;
```

More info about LINQ [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)